# How to show additional SP task list fields in CQWP

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-query-web-part

I have about 3-4 SP Task lists in a site collection and I am using Content query web part to show all tasks from these task lists across the site collection. The tasks show up fine but I am only seeing one column "Task Name" as clickable URL. Can we add other columns to show up there as well? I want to show Start Date, due date, assigned to, task status, description and one custom choice column called Investor.

How can it be customized to include other fields in CQWP itself? FYI, I am working with SPonline. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can customize the item display template of the CQWP to show more item information.

By default, the XSL style sheet that controls the presentation of the Content By Query Web Part renders item columns. The XSL style sheets are located in site collection Style Library (\Style Library\XSL Style Sheets).

*(If the Style Library is missing, check if the publishing features are activated:
1. On the Site Collection Features page, activate SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure.
2. On the Site Features page, activate SharePoint Server Publishing.)*

Here is a demo about how to display additional fields in CQWP. Export CQWP and change the xml file for each site.

https://www.credera.com/blog/technology-insights/microsoft-solutions/displaying-custom-fields-sharepoint-2013-content-query-web-part/

Information about how to customize the HTML editor and the CQWP:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ee558385(v%3doffice.14)

*These article also apply to SPO.*

Note: Use the managed property of the field and ensure the managed property is retrievable.

Comment: Thanks. One question, can users mark a task as completed from CQWP itself like we do in task list. Is that possible, I trying to see if there is a way to make edits for tasks in CQWP.